# Logistic regression to test difference between two groups with multiple levels

Tags: logistic, interaction, odds

I have a dataset (see example below) with 1200 rows and 3 columns: dependent_var (yes and no), group_var (1 and 2) and var1 (1, 2, 3 and 4), where var1 belongs to either group 1 or 2. The two groups are independent.

dependent_var Yes Yes Yes No No No No Yes No
group_var 1 1 2 2 2 1 1 1 2
var1 1 2 3 3 4 4 4 1 2

I want to compare the two groups (1 and 2) to see if there is a difference between 1, 2, 3 and 4 of whether a person answered yes.

To do this I chose Logistic regression (but I'm not sure this is correct).

```
log odds = α + β1 * var1 + β2 * group_var + β3 * var1 * group_var
```

Then I get this output, but how do I interpret the results?

```
  Call:
glm(formula = dependent_var ~ relevel(factor(var1), ref = 3) + factor(group_var) +
    relevel(factor(var1), ref = 3) * factor(group_var), 
    family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = df)

Coefficients:
                                                         Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                                              -0.3301    0.17557  -3.132 0.000722 ***
factor(group_var)2                                       -0.3556    0.12346  -2.157 0.025245 *  
relevel(factor(var1), ref = 3)1                           0.35529    0.10214   1.121 0.281122    
relevel(factor(var1), ref = 3)2                            0.76383   0.19928   3.922 1.11e-06 ***
relevel(factor(var1), ref = 3)4                           0.20483    0.20845   0.982 0.225801    
factor(group_var)2:relevel(factor(var1), ref = 3)1        -0.02508   0.39157  -0.323 0.931782    
factor(group_var)2:relevel(factor(var1), ref = 3)2        -0.51871   0.25732  -1.302 0.142303    
factor(group_var)2:relevel(factor(var1), ref = 3)4         0.03693   0.49130   0.261 0.972011    
---
    Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 2201.6  on 1631  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 2138.2  on 1624  degrees of freedom
  (240 observations deleted due to missingness)
AIC: 2154.2

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
```

And for the log odds I get:

```
 (Intercept)                                         factor(group_var)2 
          0.6434824                                            0.761233 
    relevel(factor(var1), ref = 3)1              relevel(factor(var1), ref = 3)2
          1.3742596                                            2.731632 
relevel(factor(var1), ref = 3)4    factor(year)2:relevel(factor(var1), ref = 3)1 
          1.377421                                             0.7321576 
factor(group_var)2:relevel(factor(var1), ref = 3)2
    0.651302 
factor(group_var)2:relevel(factor(var1), ref = 3)4 
     1.032011
```

And confidence intervals for the log odds

```
                                                        2.5 % 97.5 %
(Intercept)                                             0.485  0.821
factor(group_var)2                                      0.441  0.977
relevel(factor(var1), ref = 3)1                         0.876  1.907
relevel(factor(var1), ref = 3)2                         1.867  3.999
relevel(factor(var1), ref = 3)4                         0.915  1.749
factor(group_var)2:relevel(factor(var1), ref = 3)1      0.611  1.782
factor(group_var)2:relevel(factor(var1), ref = 3)2      0.387  1.235
factor(group_var)2:relevel(factor(var1), ref = 3)4      0.692  1.551
```

Comment: is `var1` categorical? If so, perhaps you should be using dummy variables.

Comment: var1 is on a Likert scale depending on what answer a person has chosen (1 through 4).